# Getting error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getKey does not exist. in laravel, how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, entrust

During assigning roles in laravel by using entrust i am getting error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getKey does not exist.
>   My code is :

```php
    $record = new User();
    $data = $request->all();
    $record->fill($data);
    $record->save();
    $roles = [1, 3]
    $role = Role::whereIn('id', $roles)->get();
    $record->attachRole($role);
```

Comment: you can attact role to user what is `record` here.?

Comment: You are fetching roles from the database with the id `1` and `3` but you are not doing anything with them? What is `$record` and what is `$role`?

Comment: @Remul updated code

Comment: `$role` is currently a collection of roles, did you try attaching only one role e.g.: `$record->attachRole(1)`, it is unclear from the documentation if you can pass multiple roles to `attachRole`

Comment: one role is working,

Answer (score 1):

You are using [attachRole](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustUserTrait.php#L250) which is used to attach a single role to a user.

You want to use [attachRoles](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustUserTrait.php#L286) to attach multiple roles to a user.

So in your case:

```
$record = new User();
$record->fill($request->all());
$record->save();

$roles = Role::whereIn('id', [1, 3])->get();
$record->attachRoles($roles);
```